# What is the least amount of straight cuts that should be made to get squares from a rectangle?

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

> Rachel has a rectangular piece of cloth which measures $2$ meters
> large and $0.2$ meters wide. She is to use a guillotin which can only
> makes cuts of $60$ cm of maximum in length. Another constrain in this
> guillotin is that it can only cut one layer of this cloth. Using this
> information, how many straight cuts minimum can Rachel make in order
> to get from such fabric $10$ square pieces of $20\,cm$ from each
> side?.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{3 cuts}\\
2.&\textrm{1 cut}\\
3.&\textrm{2 cuts}\\
4.&\textrm{4 cuts}\\
\end{array}$

I'm not sure how to solve this question regarding cuts. But I believe that a way to reduce the number of cuts will require to fold the piece. But in this case this seems not to be possible because there is a condition in the problem which is forbidding to do such approach.

My initial approach was to make the necessary cuts to make some sort of grid which could I guess reduce the number of cuts but 10 is not a perfect square. Therefore what sort of logic should be here?.

I've went in circles for long on this question so I will really appreciate someone could give me a hand with this.

Therefore what should be the way to go here?. Can someone help me here please?. I'm confused.

Comment: I think the question allows folding, but a guillotin cut cannot be through multiple layers.

Comment: I brute forced a 4 cut solution.  If this is the answer, there must be a proof as to why this is the minimum required.

Answer (score 1):

To cut the strip of cloth, it only takes 9 cuts of 20 cm, and each cut of the guillotin cuts through 60 cm at most, so at least 3 cuts are necessary.

Number the cuts $1$ to $9$ sequentially, and the resultant squares $0$ to $9$.

Align cut $1$ under the guillotin, then fold two right angled triangles on the strip around cuts $2$ and $3$ so that the strip goes back under the guillotin, and align cut $4$ under the guillotin next to cut $1$.

(Fold twice like (B) in this random image found in Google:
[image]
)

Do the same thing to align cut $7$ under the guillotin. With cut $1, 4, 7$ all aligned side by side, one guillotin cut of 60 cm would do all the 3 20-cm cuts.

Now squares 1-3, squares 4-6, squares 7-9 are on separated pieces of cloth, and they can be aligned freely to make the remaining 6 cloth-cuts in 2 guillotin cuts.

The optimal answer is 3 guillotin cuts.